# iPhone : Problem with Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I got a sample app from internet. In which I am trying to change it's Orientation.

For changing the orientation I have write following coding :

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return YES;
    }
```

And also made changes in xib's Auto-sizing.

But still its not working. What should I do ?

Comment: post more details and what problem do you meet?

Comment: more detail need about ur app if app is using tabbar then do yes in all controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, however if you are writing an application that uses a TabBarController you have to ensure that all viewcontrollers return `YES` from this method (alternative could be YES for some orientations).

Answer (score 0):

Add UISupportedInterfaceOrientations in your info.plist and within that add all the four orientations like UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and make all the four enabled.

Comment: These are only used while starting the app. They do not affect the behavior once you are in the app.